# Coding a server that is *not* 'thread per client'

Tags: .net, client-server, tcp

Using .NET what is the basic algorithm of a server that is *not* 'thread per client' based?

**Edit** I'm looking for a basic 3, 4 maybe 5 line algorithm/psuedocode/pattern that describes the general process the server is using.

Something opposite to this:

```
open a server socket // this uses the port the clients know about

while(running)    
  client_socket = server_socket.listen    
  fork(new handler_object(client_socket))
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What aspects of "thread per client" do you want to avoid?

Answer (score 2):

An event loop.  Wait for sockets to become writable, write to them, wait for connections, accept them, etc.  This approach is more scalable than threads in most cases, as you usually don't need more than a closure to keep track of a client's state.  (You certainly don't need a whole process, as prefork servers seem to think.)

Answer (score 2):

In a rather broad and general way of describing things (ie, not specific to .net or any other platform), services are programmed in one of two ways, or a combination of both.

thread per connection: as you note, this uses a single scheduling entity, such as a kernel thread or process, or possibly a lighter thread or co-routine implemented by the platform in user space, such that each process need only concern itself with handling a single request, in order.

example pseudocode:

```
function run(connection)
    while(connection is open)
        frobnicate(connection)

function main
    listener = new Listener(port)
    threads = new Collection<Thread>()
    while(running)
        connection = listener.accept()
        threads.add(new Thread(run, connection))
    join(threads)
    exit()
```

Important features of the above sample:

- this follows the thread per connection model, exactly as you put it.  Once the thread
  has finished working on the connection, it dies.
- If this program were to run in the real world, it would likely be alright up until it
  had to handle more than a few hundred threads.  Most platforms start to churn at about
  this level.  A few are specially designed to handle many more threads, in the tens of
  thousands of simultaneous connections.
- Although the connections are handled in a manner that is multithreaded, actually
  accepting incoming connections is handled only in the main thread, this can possibly
  be a point of DoS, if a malicious host tries to connect but deliberately fails, slowly.
- When the program detects that it is time to stop running, the main thread joins the other
  threads so that they do not die when it exits.  again, that means that the program won't
  exit until all old threads are finished handling data, which might just be never.
  An alternative would be to not use the join, in which case the other threads would be
  terminated uncerimiously.

non-blocking: a single thread of execution manages several connections, and when any given connection is stalled, because it is waiting for data to move across the network, or to be read in from disk, the process skips over it and works on another connection.

example pseudocode:

```
function main
    connections = new Collection<Connection>()
    listener = new Listener()
    connections.append(listener)
    foreach connection in connections:
        if connection.ready():
            if connection is listener: 
                connections.add(connection.accept() )
            else: 
                if connection is open:
                    nb_frobnicate(connection)
                else: 
                    connections.remove(connection)
        yield()
        if( not running )
            exit()
```

Features of this snippet:

- In the multi-threaded version, each thread was handling only a single connection.  if
  that connection isn't ready to be used, the thread blocks, and another thread can do
  work.  if `frobnicate` blocked in this implementation, it would be a disaster.  other
  connections might be able to do work, even if one connection happens not to be ready.
  To address this, an alternative function is used, which takes care to only use
  non-blocking operations on the connection.  these reads and writes return immediately, 
  and return with values that tell the caller how much work they were able to do. if that
  happens happens to be no work at all, the program will just have to try again as soon 
  as it knows that the connection is ready for more work.  I've changed the name to
  `nb_frobnicate` to indicate that this function is being careful to be non-blocking.
- Most platforms supply a function that can abstract out the loop over the connections, 
  and checking if each one has data.  This is going to be called either `select()` or
  `poll()` (both may be available).  Even so, I've chosen to show it this way, because
  you might want to work on more than just a network connection.  As far as I know, there
  is no way to wait on every possible blocking operation generically, If you also need to 
  wait on disk IO (windows only), timers, hardware interrupts (like screen refresh) you'll
  have to manually poll different event sources, kind of like this.
- at the far end of the loop is a `yield()` function, which sleeps until an IO interrupt
  happens.  This is necessary in case no IO is ready to be handled.  If we didn't do this, 
  the program would busy-wait, checking and re-checking each port, and finding that there 
  is no data ready, needlessly wasting CPU.  In case the program only needs to wait on 
  network IO (or also disk on posix systems), then `select/poll` could be invoked in
  blocking mode, and it would sleep until a network connection would be ready.  If you had
  to wait on more kinds of events, though, you'd have to use a non-blocking version of
  those functions, poll other event sources according to their idiom, and then yield once
  all would block.
- There's no equivalent here to the thread join from the previous example.  This is instead
  analogous to the non-joining behavior.  you could probably get similar behavior by 
  removing the listener from the polling collection, and then only calling exit once 
  the collection is empty.
- importantly, the entire program is composed of simple loops and function calls.  there
  is no point that incurs the cost of a context switch.  The down-side of this is that 
  the program is strictly sequential, and cannot take advantage of multiple cores, if they
  are present.  In practice this is seldom an issue, because most services will be IO
  bound, limited by the rate at which connections become ready, not the cost of the
  fictional `frobnicate()` function.

As I mentioned, these can both be used in combination, allowing for many of the advantages of multiple scheduling entities, such as better CPU utilization on multi-core systems, as well as the advantages of non-blocking, ie lower load due to fewer context switches.

example of this:

```
function worker(queue)
    connections = Collection<Connection>()
    while(running)
        while(queue not empty)
            connections.add(queue.pop)
        foreach connection in select(connections)
            if connection is open:
                nb_frobnicate(connection)
            else: 
                connections.remove(connection)

function main
    pool = new Collection<Thread, Queue<Connection> >()
    for index in num_cpus: 
        pool[index] = new Thread(worker), new Queue<Connection>
    listener = new Listener(port)
    while(running)        
        connection = listener.accept()
        selected_thread = 0
        for index in pool.length: 
            if pool[index].load() < pool[selected_thread].load()
                selected_thread = index
        pool[selected_thread].push(connection)
        pool[selected_thread].wake()
```

notes about this program:

- This creates a bunch of instances of the single threaded version, but since they are
  multithreaded, they have to communicate with each other, somehow.  this is done using
  the `Queue<Connection>` for each thread.
- Also notice that it uses the `nb_frobnicate`
  handler for the same reason as the single threaded program, and for the same reason, 
  because each thread handles more than one connection.
- The pool of worker threads is limited according to the number of processors we have.
  since there would be little benefit of having more threads waiting than can possibly 
  be running at once.  In practice, the optimum number of threads to use may vary from 
  application to application, but the number of cpu's is often a good enough guess.
- As before, the main thread accepts connections, and passes them to worker threads.
  If the thread is already done with work on other threads, waiting for them to be ready,
  then it will just sit there, even if the new connection is ready now.  To alleviate this,
  the main thread then notifies the worker thread by waking it, causing any blocking 
  operation to return.  If this had been a normal read, it would probably return an error
  code, but since we're using a `select()`, it would just return an empty list of ready
  connections, and the thread can empty its queue once more.

Edit: added code samples:

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  So a non-blocking connection is oriented more towards a thread managing objects.  Is there a general algorithm for the non-blocking method?

Answer (score 2):

A loop that calls [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.select.aspx), to determine which sockets (clients) are ready and then reads and/or writes to those sockets, doing whatever processing is necessary when no socket is ready.

Pseudo code:

```
loop {

   to_read.add(client1);
   to_read.add(client2);

   select(to_read, timeout = 0.5);

   for client in to_read { // to_read is modified by select
      data = client.read
      handle(data)
   }

   if to_read is empty {
     do_bookeeping()
   }
}
```

Comment: Looks promising.  Is there a general algorithm/psuedocode/pattern to using select?

Answer (score 2):

Ian Griffiths has an [excellent (.NET) introduction](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2004/09/23/threadless) to handling multiple clients without having to use a thread per client.

Answer (score 1):

A thread pool will allow the server to have fewer threads than clients.

Comment: Ok, so the algorithm would use the thread pool, but in what context?  What is the basic algorithm that would be used.  Just looking for 3,4,5 lines of psuedocode.

Answer (score 1):

use an event-queue and a thread-pool, e.g.:

```
when [something happens] then 
    [create an event for something]
    [put it in the queue]
```

also:

```
while [something in queue]
    if [thread is available] then
        remove [thing] from queue
        run [thing-response] on [available thread]
    else [wait a little while]
```

this architecture is quite scalable

Comment: Interesting.  How would apply that to a socket?

Comment: @[Unknown]: "connection requested" = [something happens], queue.Add(new MyEvent(MyEnum.ConnectionRequested,connectionInfo)) = create event and put in queue. Response to event type may be to check credentials (via connectionInfo), establish connection, etc. The new connection may become a source of additional events [see socket-list polling in another answer]

Comment: @[Unknown]: for all the glorious details, see the SEDA paper at MIT http://nms.lcs.mit.edu/~kandula/projects/killbots/killbots_files/seda-sosp01.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You could do a thread per request, limited by a thread pool.  But you might be interested in asynchronous methods for handling this.  This page does a good job of how async approaches work:

- http://squirl.nightmare.com/medusa/async_sockets.html

Answer (score 0):

[Socket.BeginAccept](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/libra/system.net.sockets.socket.beginaccept(VS.80).aspx) -> in callback AuthenticatedStream.[BeginAuthenticateAsServer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.negotiatestream.beginauthenticateasserver(VS.80).aspx) -> in callback Stream.[BeginRead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.negotiatestream.beginread(VS.80).aspx) -> in callback post new BeginRead, process request then Stream.[BeginWrite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.negotiatestream.beginwrite(VS.80).aspx) response.

You can take out the authenticated stream part (SSL or Kerberos/NTLM) if you *really* don't need it, and then it becomes:
[Socket.BeginAccept](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/libra/system.net.sockets.socket.beginaccept(VS.80).aspx) -> in callback socket.[BeginReceive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.beginreceive(VS.80).aspx) -> in callback post new BeginReceive, process request then socket.[BeginWrite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.beginsend(VS.80).aspx) response.

[Also see Asynchronous Server Socket Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: Could you summarize the basic algorithm being used?

Comment: Typical event driven application (events being the socket accept, read complete and write complete). Instead of stack based client state (ie. thread), you have a heap based client state (ie. an object representing the connection/state).